# Azure Function and WindowsAzure.Storage version (DLL Hell)

Tags: azure, dll, azure-functions

With VS 2017 latest update I'm creating a Azure Function project. Apparently this has a hard reference to WindowsAzure.Storage 7.2.1 build from September 2016(!) that is also referring other packages like OData, JSON etc.

Is it really advisable to downgrade to 7.2.1? (to be safe I would downgrade OData, JSON as well). This is the workaround on various blogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, at the moment you have to stick to the versions of dependencies that are used by Azure Functions runtime.